# How to figure out which distribution a package is in?

Tags: packages, installing, enumitem, distributions, macports

I just installed TeX Live on my Mac with Macports. I wanted to use the `enumitem` package and was told that LaTeX couldn't find the file when I tried to compile.

I installed the texlive-basic distribution – is there a way to figure out the smallest distribution that contains the `enumitem` package?

Alternately, if I download the package where do I want to put it?

Comment: There should be some tool in your distribution that lets you install individual packages.

Comment: I'd need help with that too - a package manager? It's TexLive via Macports. The only thing I know I can do is install a much larger TeX distribution.

Comment: Usually TeX Live should have a utility that installs individual packages. However, I don't have a Mac, so I don't know anything about Macports and what it does to TeX Live.

Comment: What is the difference between TeXLive from Macports and MacTeX? doesn't the Macports version provide the tlmgr tool? MacTeX even have a more mac'ified gui for it (though I've forgotten the name of it). Usually I do not understand why people don't just install everything, true you will never need most of it, but disk space is cheap and it is a lot easier to handle, than trying to figure out which collection one need to install.

Comment: By far the preferred way to install TeX Live on a Mac is to use the [MacTeX distribution](http://tug.org/mactex). This installs everything you would need, and access to the TeX Live package manager (either through the command line or a very nice GUI TeXLive Utility) to keep everything updated. Although the initial install is huge, it will cause you far fewer problems in the long run. (Plus most Mac users will assume that's how your system is set up, so getting help will be easier.)

Comment: @Alan: Could you put that comment as an answer?

Comment: @Joseph Ok.  It's now an official answer.

Answer (score 5):

By far the preferred way to install TeX Live on a Mac is to use the [MacTeX distribution](http://tug.org/mactex). This installs everything you would need, and access to the TeX Live package manager (either through the command line or a very nice GUI TeXLive Utility) to keep everything updated. Although the initial install is huge, it will cause you far fewer problems in the long run.

If you truly need a *small* installation, MacTeX also provides the [BasicTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/morepackages.html) package, which is only 69 MB. Once you've installed that you can use either `tlmgr` or TeXLive Utility to install added functionality.

Either of these routes is to be preferred over MacPorts, IMO, because MacTeX is always up-to-date with respect to TeXLive (because it *is* a TeXLive distribtion), and can be kept updated throughout the year with the package manager.  Additionally,  most Mac users will assume that's how your system is set up, so getting help will be easier.

Comment: I don't really think MacTeX is a reasonable choice for the "smallest distribution" that was asked about.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber Thanks for your comment.  I've added mention of the 69 MB MacTeX BasicTeX distribution, which certainly meets that criterion.

Comment: It certainly does! Thanks for taking the time to update an older answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [list](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/TeXLivePackages) of the package contents on the MacPorts site. According to it, you'll find `enumitem` in the `texlive-latex-extra` package.